# WPF Full screen focus issue?

Tags: wpf

I've a bit of an issue with a WPF application I recently wrote, which I'm hoping is something trivial
but I can't figure out an appropriate way to debug.

My WPF application is a full screen application, that hides the mouse and is intended to be driven via the keyboard and as far as I'm aware is the only application running on the machine (it's placed in the Startup folder on a windows machine). The application itself is a clock/stopwatch style application for talks so recieves input at fairly infrequent intervals.

The problem that has been found, is that after a period of inactivity the application stops responding to keyboard input and requires a click of the mouse to start working again, almost as though it has lost focus. I believe all the power settings are turned off on the machine, but I'd be grateful if anyone could think of anything else that might be causing the problem, or if there's a way I can ensure the application never loses focus. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could trying wiring up an event handler in the FocusLost event to set Focus back on the Window

Comment: Have tried hooking this up, with the Deactivated event too. Looks like the right way to go, so marking as correct unless it fails to work again :)